# pcm_open and pcm_is_ready call fail as pcm->fd returns negative integer

Tags: android, tinyalsa

While trying tinyalsa in Android 9.0 pcm_is_ready call fails as pcm->fd is < 0.
This is because pcm->fd = open(fn, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK); open call is failing.
And i have made selinux as permissive. and given chmod 777 -R to /dev/snd
So how to solve this issue in android???

i have made selinux as permissive. and given chmod 777 -R to /dev/snd

Comment: I'd recommend, before you do anything else, to check `errno` if the `open` call fails. This way you'll have a little more information to work with.

Comment: errno is 13 which is permission denied..

Comment: Hi Jan,when is check in /proc/asound and do cat /devices cat /cards cat /pcm all of them are fine. There is no issue. But when i do cat /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c it says File descriptor in bad state.. so how do i solve this issue

Comment: @Archie The device must be configured/prepared (with `ioctl()` system call) before read/write. That's why it is in bad state. TinyALSA handles this for you.